# C clone function not executing with CLONE_NEWPID | SIGCHLD flags

Tags: c, stdout

I have the following code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<sched.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>

static char child_stack[2048];

int x = 10;

static int child_fn() {
    printf("Pid: %ld\n", (long) getpid());
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("before= %d\n", x);
    errno = 0;
    pid_t child_pid = clone(&child_fn, (void *) child_stack+1024, CLONE_NEWPID | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    if(child_pid == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("clone()= %ld\n", (long) child_pid);
        printf("after= %d\n", x);

        while(waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) < 0 && errno == EINTR) {
            printf("waiting\n");
            continue;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

the output I get is:

```
before= 10
clone()= 16
after= 10
```

This means that the `child_fn` did get assigned a Pid, which is `child_pid`. But the `printf` inside the `child_fn` either didn't get executed, or it may be printing in a different stdout scope? Either way, what can be the reason for this, and how to debug it. I'm just starting with namespaces so don't know much about them.

Answer (score 1):

If I run your original code using `gdb`, I see that it is failing with a `SIGSEGV`:

```
$ gcc -o clone clone.c
$ sudo gdb ./clone
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/lars/tmp/clone 
before= 10
[New process 10768]
clone()= 10768
after= 10

Thread 2.1 "clone" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to process 10768]
0x00007ffff7a5e9de in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I suspect that your `child_stack` is too small. You've allocated 2048 bytes, but you're only using half of that.  If I modify the `clone` call to look like this:

```
pid_t child_pid = clone(&child_fn, (void *) child_stack+2048, CLONE_NEWPID | SIGCHLD, NULL);
```

Then on my system it seems to run correctly:

```
$ sudo gdb ./clone
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/lars/tmp/clone 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.24-9.fc25.x86_64
before= 10
[New process 10807]
clone()= 10807
after= 10
Pid: 1
[Inferior 2 (process 10807) exited normally]
```